# Learning PHP String Reversal

Tags: php, string

```
$original = "test";
$reversed = strrev($original)
echo "Original String: $original";
echo "Reversed String: $reversed";
```

I'm learning PHP, why does the above script give this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) index.php : eval()'d code on line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
$reversed = strrev($original);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't accept now because it's too early but I will soon!

Comment: With 30k rep you should now better that such typo questions are off-topic and there are hundreds of dupes.